# How to join tables of events to report non-events?

Tags: join, self-join, full-outer-join

Employees must complete continuing education modules to stay competent. I need to build a report showing supervisors which modules their employees have – and have not -- completed.

I have a simple table of employees and their supervisors. Each row is an employee, with two columns: Supervisor Name and Employee Name. Call this the Staff table.

| Supervisor | Employee Name |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Jack |

I have a table of module completions. Each row is an event -- a module completion, with columns for the Module Code, Employee Name, and Date of Completion. Call this the Completions table.

| Employee Name | Module Code | Date of Completion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | MOD1 | 2022-01-20 |
| Jack | MOD2 | 2022-01-21 |

I have a table of all the Modules. Each row is a module, with columns for the Module Code and other module-level information, such as Module Name, etc.

| Module Code | Module Name | Format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MOD1 | Important Content | Online |
| MOD2 | Super Important Content | Online |
| MOD3 | Oh so Critical Content | In person |
| MOD4 | You Must Learn This Content | In person |

I can join the Staff table to the Completion table on Employee Name. That gives me a list of employees and the modules they have completed.

| Employee Name | Module Code | Completion Date | Completions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | MOD1 | 2022-01-20 | 1 |
| Jack | MOD2 | 2022-01-21 | 1 |

I’m halfway there.

The challenge is how to report the *uncompleted* modules as well, so that we see this:

| Employee Name | Module Code | Completion Date | Completions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | MOD1 | 2022-01-20 | 1 |
| Jack | MOD2 | 2022-01-21 | 1 |
| Jack | MOD3 |  | 0 |
| Jack | MOD4 |  | 0 |

By what configuration of joins among the Staff, Completions, and Modules tables can I report completions of *all* modules for *every* employee, even there is no completion date for some modules?

I'm stumped. I'm imagining different kinds of joins -- some kind of full outer join of Completions and Modules, or some kind of self join of Completions that reports a sum of all completions for all modules for every employee -- but I've reached the current limit of my skill.

Comment: How do we know which modules each employee must complete? or must each employee complete ALL modules?  If so you need to cross join employee with module to get all the modules each employee completes then LEFT join it to your current results.  So: `.. .FROM SupervisorEmployee CROSS JOIN Modules LEFT JOIN Completions  on {keys} WHERE...`  Note the cross join results in a Cartesian product meaning every row in the SupervisorEmployee will be joined with every row in Modules.  So each employ is assigned each module and then completions simply shows if they have/have not completed.

Comment: An alternative would be to simply write two queries one with completions one without and UNION those two.. But you'd yet have to identify which modules an employee must complete and if all a `cross join` is what you're after.

Comment: @xQbert Which modules different employees complete is a good question but for now I'm going with all employees must complete all modules, so I like your CROSS JOIN idea.

Comment: Give it a try see if it meets your needs!  if not, add a minimally complete verified example and expected results.  We can work through that.    you can even use a site like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to build your sample.  keep in mind if you have 1000 employees and 1000 modules your record count will be 1000*1000.... so caution as data can get big fast.  you may want to limit to 1 or 2 modules and 2-3 employees to vet the SQL first then open it up to more once you know it's doing what you want

Comment: @xQbert This CROSS JOIN strategy worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: Great keep up the good work and quality when asking questions.  the time spent putting your question together made understanding it pretty easily to isolate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know what modules each employee has been assigned.  We then assume each module must be associated to each employee and we build that assocation.

To do this we use a `CROSS JOIN` which is every record of one table related to every record of another table.  Caution as this results in a Cartesian product. (1000*1000) = 1,000,000 records! but each employee is then assigned a module.

```
SELECT ...
FROM SupervisorEmployee E 
CROSS JOIN Modules  M -- This cross join ensure every employee is assigned every 
                      -- record.  note there is no ON clause when using a cross join.
LEFT JOIN Completions C 
       on {keys} 
WHERE...
```

NOTE: Since we are using a left join.  the where clause should only have limits on the SupervisorEmploye and Modules table.  It should not have a limit on the completions table or it will negate the left join.  (you can do it but you have to use an or and handle nulls it's just simpler to not put limits here)

If you need to limit on completions; do so using the On criteria so the reduction occurs before/as the join occurs and you retain the records without a completion.